# Problema con Array Push

Tags: php, array, poo

Estoy haciendo unas practicas ya que estoy aprendiendo POO, pero me quedo atorado en una clase simulando un carrito, el codigo de la clase es:

```
class ShopingCart
{   
    private $contenidoCarrito;

    function __construct(){
        $this->contenidoCarrito = array();
    }

    public function expressAdd($sku){
        $addItem = array('sku' => $sku, 'qty' => '1');
        $this->contenidoCarrito = array_push($this->contenidoCarrito, $addItem);
    }

    public function showCart(){
        print_r($this->contenidoCarrito);
    }
}
```

La intención es generar un array donde colocaría los sku y cantidad de los productos, al instanciarlos puedo ver que el array addItem se creo correctamente, pero tras hacer el array_push no hace nada, la funcion showCart siempre me muestra un array vacio.

La estructura de archivos es:
**config** -> Esta disponible en todas las páginas y lo incluyo mediante require, en este archivo genero el objeto *$carrito*

```
require_once __DIR__.'/modules/ShopingCart.php';
$carrito = new ShopingCart;
```

**catalogo** -> Muestra los productos de la DB y tiene un botón que permite agregar un solo item del producto

```
class ListarProductos {

    public function listado(){
        $database = new ConecctionDataBase;
        $conexion = $database->conectar();

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM careyou_catalogo JOIN catalogo_inventario ON careyou_catalogo.id = catalogo_inventario.productoId AND disponible=1";
        $consulta = $conexion->query($sql);

        while ($data = $consulta->fetch_assoc()) {
            printf("
                        <div class='card'>
                            <img src='assets/catalogo/{$data['imagen']}' class='card-img-top img-fluid' alt=''>
                            <div class='card-body'>
                                <h5 class='card-title'>{$data['nombre']}</h5>
                                <p class='card-text'>{$data['descripcion']}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class='card-footer'>
                                <span id='evaluate'>
                                    <button type='button' id='{$data['sku']}' class='btn btn-purple' value='{$data['sku']}'>Ver Detalles</button>
                                </span>
                                <span id='addToCart'>
                                    <button type='button' id='{$data['sku']}' class='btn btn-info' value='{$data['sku']}'><i class='fas fa-cart-plus'></i> Agregar al Carrito</button>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            ");
        }

        $consulta->free();
        $conexion->close();
    }
}
```

**additem.js** -> Pasa el valor del botón Añadir a un php donde llamo al método expressAdd y le paso el valor del sku. Ej. 0001000002

```
$("#addToCart button").click(function(){
        var addSku = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '../cart.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {skuCode: addSku, type: 'express'},
            success: function(itemAdded){
                console.log(itemAdded);
            }
        })

    })
```

**cart** -> Recibe el valor de AJAX y evalua que metodo usar mediante switch

```
require_once __DIR__.'/config.php';

/**
 * Controlador del carrito de compras
 */
$sku = limpiar($_POST['skuCode']);
$typ = limpiar($_POST['type']);

switch ($typ) {
    case 'express':
        var_dump($sku);
        $carrito->expressAdd($sku);
        break;

    default:
        # code...
        break;
}
```

**debug ->** es un archivo que su única función es la de llamar al método showCart

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../config.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/../modules/ShopingCart.php';

var_dump($carrito->showCart());
```

Comment: Agrega como haces la instancia

Comment: Creo primero el objeto $carrito = new ShopingCart;  y posteriormente hago la instancia de la función con $carrito->expressAdd($sku);

Answer (score 0):

Considero que tu ejercicio puedes hacerlo así:

- Declaras como propiedades tipadas *(desde PHP 7.4)* de la clase a:

  - contenidoCarrito
  - sku
  - addItem
- Posterior como el método `expressAdd()` solo se encargará de tomar los valores de un array y con ellos llenar otro y dar el valor de *$sku* a la clave $sky entonces que sea `void`
- Nuestro siguiente método que se llama `showCart()` devolverá un valor de tipo *array* y solo haremos un retorno de la propiedad `$contenidoCarrito`
- No tiene caso un método constructor pues no es la clase en si la que espera un valor que asignar a `$sku`sino un método interno de está que es la que lo va a usar
- Continuando con lo anterior, lo único que deberás hacer es a dicha propiedad igualarla a un array vacío
- A pesar de que en mi anterior propuesta lo había hecho, no veo sentido de que la propiedad `$contenidoCarrito` sea igualada a la acción que ejecuta `array_push`; es más sencillo y funcional solo usar este método dentro de `expressAdd()`

Código **versión PHP 7.4**:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);

class ShopingCart
{
    public array $contenidoCarrito = [];
    public int   $sku;
    public array $addItem;

    public function expressAdd(int $sku): void
    {
        $this->addItem = array("sku" => $sku, "qty" => 1);
        array_push($this->contenidoCarrito, $this->addItem);
    }

    public function showCart():array
    {
        return $this->contenidoCarrito;
    }
}

$carrito = new ShopingCart;
$carrito->expressAdd(12);

var_dump($carrito->showCart());
```

Con esta salida:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["sku"]=>
    int(12)
    ["qty"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

Código **versión PHP 7.3.5**

```
<?php 

class ShopingCart
{
    public $contenidoCarrito = [];
    public $sku;
    public $addItem;

    public function expressAdd(int $sku)
    {
        $this->addItem = array("sku" => $sku, "qty" => 1);
        array_push($this->contenidoCarrito, $this->addItem);
    }

    public function showCart()
    {
        return $this->contenidoCarrito;
    }
}

$carrito = new ShopingCart;
$carrito->expressAdd(12);

var_dump($carrito->showCart());
```

> La salida seguirá siendo la misma

Comment: Implementé el código que mencionas, pero me ocasiona un error, si le quito el tipo a los argumentos trabaja, pero al mostrar el carrito lo muestra como vacío como si no se hiciera el array_push.

Comment: @NatNajera que versión de PHP usas?, usando el código tal cual lo puse te da error?

Comment: Si, para ser mas específico me genera: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'array' (T_ARRAY), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in . La versión de PHP es 7.3.11

Comment: Es por tu versión de PHP @NatNajera deja edito

Comment: Listo @NatNajera ya edité y dejé tanto la primer respuesta como una que te funcione en tu versión de PHP

Comment: implementando la solución para mi versión de PHP sigo con el problema de que no se agrega. Marca el índice siempre como 0 pese a que pase diferentes productos y al ver su contenido lo marca como 0. ¿Será problema de la estructura de archivos? El objeto lo creo en archivo config que esta dispónible en todas las páginas, posteriormente llamo al método a traves de un php que recibe el parametro sku a traves de AJAX y el mostrar el carrito esta en otro archivo llamado debug que solo muestra el array vacio.

Comment: Ahh! ahora noto que aqui están involucrados mas detalles, eso deberías agregarlo editando tu pregunta

Comment: Pregunta editada con mayor información